# Subgroup of Solvable group is Solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I know this has probably been posted about 934345 times, but I wanted someone to look over my proof for me because I haven't seen somebody do it this way.

Claim: If $G$ is a solvable group and $H \leq G$, then $H$ is a solvable group.

*Proof:* Since $G$ is solvable, it's derived series terminates

$G \leq G^2 \leq G^3 \leq ... \leq G^n = 1$

Consider the series for $H:$

$H \leq H \cap G^2 \leq H \cap G^3 \leq ... \leq 1$

Now, I need to prove that $H \cap G^{i+1} \triangleleft H \cap G^i$ and then that $\frac{H \cap G^i}{H \cap G^{i+1}}$ is abelian.

To show normality, consider the following arguement:

$[G^i \cap H, G^{i+1} \cap H]$ $\leq [G^i,G^{i+1}] \cap [H,H]$ $\leq [G^i,G^{i}] \cap H \leq G^{i+1} \cap H$

Keeping this in mind, let $x \in H \cap G^i$ and $y \in H \cap G^{i+1}$. To show normality, we need $xyx^{-1} \in H \cap G^{i+1}$.

But from the arguement above we know that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H \cap G^{i+1}$

And since $y \in H \cap G^{i+1}$ we have that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}y = xyx^{-1} \in H \cap G^{i+1}$.

Thus we have showed each term of the sequence is normal in the previous one.

The fact the the factors are abelian follows from the following:

$[G^i \cap H, G^{i} \cap H] \leq G^{i+1} \cap H$.

Therefore $H$ is solvable.

The main reason I posted this because I wanted to know if the way that i proved normality was legit or if there is an error in the logic somewhere.

Comment: You can call such groups solvable or soluble but not soluable.

Comment: Using exponents for indices is terrible notation, since in general $G^n$ already has a meaning: the subgroup generated by the $n$th powers of elements of $G$. The Derived Series is usually denoted $G'$, $G^{(2)}$, $G^{(3)}$, etc.

Comment: Other than that is the proof legit?